# Tried it all, body background-img extends beyond the content

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I've tried it all, or probably not since I can't get it to work, but anyway, I'd really appreciate some help!

bootingup.se/test

I've walked through a bunch of guides on the issue, and still can't figure out why the footer won't anchor itself to the bottom of the page, or rather, why my body extends past the content of my page. My guess is that it has something to do with some CSS overruling something else. Any suggestions as to why this might happen?

I hope I've provided enough info, anything else that needs to be included?

Regards,

Comment: can you provide a code snippet of what exactly doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add overflow:hidden; to .site

```
.site{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I've spent a long time trying to figure this one out!

Comment: Another thing, if I use an anchor link on the page, the same issue reoccurs, why is this, and how do I rid of it?